# django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing error Connecting Postgres to Django?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

This is my first time that i am using other database than sqlite3 with django ,so i go ahead with postgres ,install it on my machine and created the user and db but after config the setting.py when i migrate i got this error

```
# database config

DB_NAME = 'django_chat_db'
DB_USER = "django"
DB_PASSWORD = "password"
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

ERRORs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" bigint NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:   

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 70, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 447, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 199, in execute    
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for schema public  
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" bigint NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\src\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\src\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute   
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv 
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute       
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped        
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 107, in migrate     
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "C:\Users\rakib\OneDrive\Desktop\Real Time Messenger\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 72, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (permission denied for schema public     
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" bigint NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^
)
```

i've been searching for the solution but couldn't find any that can work for me,can someone tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is the authentication here: `permission denied for schema public`. Did you create the database with the postgres user? in that case you want to also use the postgres user in your config

Comment: yes , but i grant all previlleges to the other user it should work right?

Comment: I don't know what privileges you mean here but I'd strongly suggest either creating and using your database with the same user. Otherwise check the docs to see what you may have done wrong with your django user: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html